# cURL Chain Issues

Tags: ssl, curl

On Ubuntu 13.10 running the system curl:

```
curl --version
curl 7.32.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.32.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

I'm getting an SSL error when trying to connect to [`https://blog.pinboard.in`](https://blog.pinboard.in).

```
curl -v https://blog.pinboard.in/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1365a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1365a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to blog.pinboard.in port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 67.23.8.22...
* Connected to blog.pinboard.in (67.23.8.22) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Using curl 7.30.0 on Mac OS 10.9 there is no SSL error:

```
curl -v https://blog.pinboard.in
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fbe79003a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fbe79003a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to blog.pinboard.in port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 67.23.8.22...
* Connected to blog.pinboard.in (67.23.8.22) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.0 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.pinboard.in
* Server certificate: Gandi Standard SSL CA
* Server certificate: UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: blog.pinboard.in
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:52:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:52:00 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8o is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
< Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 16:38:20 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 16:38:20 GMT
< ETag: "21c05e-e006-4f4f847c4f700"
ETag: "21c05e-e006-4f4f847c4f700"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 57350
Content-Length: 57350
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8

< 
* Connection #0 to host blog.pinboard.in left intact
```

There is also no SSL error when trying to visit the page in a browser. The [Qualys SSL Labs results](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=blog.pinboard.in&hideResults=on) say that the chain is incomplete so I guess browsers and Apple curl can work around this issue.

Is there any way to get curl on ubuntu to connect without disabling SSL with `-k` or downloading certificates manually?

Comment: Whoever runs that site needs to fix the issue. They have a lot of problems with their SSL, and this is only one of them.